# How to know if certain IP is blocked in china?

Tags: spam-blocker

After changing my IP, my site no longer works in China. What can I do to test that more thoroughly? Is there a way to do so?

I do not want to block Chinese visitors. I want the block removed by using an IP that is not blocked in China.

Answer (score 2):

[www.greatfirewallofchina.org](http://www.greatfirewallofchina.org/) is a tool built just for this. [Here](http://www.viewdns.info/chinesefirewall/) and [here](http://www.websitepulse.com/help/testtools.china-test.html) are other tools with similar functionality.